# Is there a way to use Wygwam on the Forum module?

Tags: wygwam

I am setting up an EE Forum for a client and would like to know if there is a way to change the default text entry field to a Wygwam field.

Thanks,

Forrest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fmz - there is not a way to use Wygwam with the forums; though since you have control over the forum themes you may be able to get a CKEditor directly in there.

Comment: Hi Lisa, congrats on your move to P&T. Thanks for the response. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I got CKEditor working; you can see my answer here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/17278/221.

Lisa's right: it's not WYGWAM, but since WYGWAM is, at heart, CKEditor, you can get CKEditor in there. So if you have WYGWAM, you can use its CKEditor files, rather than duplicating code.